# Multiple elasticsearch filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, tire

I am using Tire for rails to integrate elasticsearch. This bit is quite confusing and I want to make sure I'm doing this right.

Is this how I apply multiple filters? I'm basically trying to check 'mixtape_id IS NULL AND artist_id IS NOT NULL'

```
  def self.search(query)
    tire.search() do
      query  { string query }
      filter :exists, { field: 'artist_id' }
      filter :not, { exists: { field: 'mixtape_id' } }
    end
  end
```

Here is my second attempt, still doesnt appear to work

```
  def self.search(query)
    tire.search(load: true) do
      query  { string query }
      filter :and, [
        { exists: { field: 'artist_id' } },
        { not: { exists: { field: 'mixtape_id' } } }
      ]
    end
  end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I mostly had it working the whole time, I stupidly forgot to force reindexing each time though *sigh*. Here is some cleaned up code that takes advantage of the `missing` filter.

```
  def self.search(query)
    tire.search load: { include: { artist: :attachments } } do
      query  { string query }
      filter :and, [
        { exists:  { field: 'artist_id' } },
        { missing: { field: 'mixtape_id' } }
      ]
    end
  end
```